# Ant : pass list param to java

Tags: java, ant

I have an ant target like this

```
<target name="createUser">
        <antcall target="createUser">
            <param name="userName" value="${userName}"/>
            <param name="password" value="${password}"/>
            <param name="roles" value="${roles}"/>
        </antcall>
</target>
```

the ant call is like this

```
<target name="createUser">
        <java classname="createUser" inputstring="">
            <classpath refid="libClasspath"/>   
            <arg value="${userName}"/>
            <arg value="${password}"/>
            <arg value="${roles}"/>
        </java>
    </target>
```

I want the role param be a list and i can recove it in java like this

```
List<String> roles = args[2];
```

it's possible ? and how to do it,
thanks.